# Bootstrap's modal content from another page is not changing as per request

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal

I have dynamic links that calling a dynamic content in bootstarp modal.

dynamic links

```
    <li><a href="/manage/user-log-details/user/' + res.learner_id + 
    '/'+org_id+'" data-target="#logdiv" data-toggle="modal">Log 
    details</a></li>
    ....
     ....
```

res.learner_id , org_id comming from a foreach

```
      <div id="logdiv" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <!-- Content will be loaded here from "remote.php" file -->
        </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Content is loading one time. this not changing as per request. (/manage/user-log-details)The link will generate appropriate content in php.

Comment: Any error in console? Can you see the request in the network dev console? Do you clean the modal before re-upload the data? How data are loaded?

Comment: No error in console. request is calling only in first request. I clean the modal but no changes

Comment: thanks for your comment

Comment: maybe your href is changed after the first request? Because if you press again and it doesn't make a request there is a problem... Otherwise you would see the request in the network console